# tab button does not show me the path of folder

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code. I try to use a function called fitz.open which need me to declare a filename. But when i  type fitz.open('  , it does not show me the paths of folders for me to select. Does anyone know what is the cause behind?

I tried 'tab' in cmd and it works. But it does not work in python script in VS code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unsure about your problem. As far as I understand, you are entering some command inside a `.py` file and expect VS Code to provide you with paths as auto complete (as in the terminal/shell?)?
Not 100% sure however I think this is not possible in native VS Code (maybe there is a plugin).

However you can right click on a folder or file in VS Code and select `Copy Path` or `Copy Relative Path` and than paste it into your `.py` file.

Answer (score 0):

Editing a .py file is not the same as using the command line: IntelliSense does not know directories/file system structure around your file.
As far as your code editing is concerned, you are just inputting a string literal... **The editor can not know in what directory the code/script will reside and be executed in the future.**
You could copy and paste the script file to another location and execute it there in the future (where your autocompleted paths/folders would be incorrect).